# Check if JToken is empty array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following, after receiving a response from an API:

```
JObject goatHerd = JObject.Parse(responseString);
JToken goat = goatHerd["value"];
```

Now `goat` will either contain an array of data, or it will be an empty array. How can I check for empty?

I tried something like this:

```
if(goat != null){}
```

Unfortunately, `goat` actually equals `{[]}` according to Visual Studio.

I can't do:

```
if(goat.length != 0){}
```

Because `.length` doesn't work with `JToken`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [HasValues](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_HasValues.htm) property:

```
if (goat.HasValues) {}
```

In addition, `JToken` supports LINQ operations, so you can also use `Any()`.

```
if (goat.Any()) {}
```

Comment: Yup. That's it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!